# Get Final Render Depsgraph

Tags: python

I am writing a simple exporter in python. I want to export the meshes as *triangle* meshes, with modifiers applied. Therefore, I want to access the evaluated version of the final render dependency graph. However, I only see one way to get a depsgraph, which is `bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()`, that returns the *viewport* depsgraph. How can I access/create the *render* depsgraph?

Answer (score 1):

As confirmed [here](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/get-render-dependency-graph/12164/2?u=bathal) by Blender devs, there is currently no way to access the render depsgraph from the python API.